# How enterprise versions of Puppet map to community versions?

Tags: puppet

In particular, which 'community' version corresponds to the current 'enterprise' one, 3.3?

I remember there was some magic involved: 'enterprise' 2.5 was 'community' 2.7 plus some GUI bells and whistles. I didn't find any definite answer on their website, hence asking here.

Answer (score 2):

PE 3.3 includes Puppet 3.6.2, PuppetDB, Facter, Hiera,...
https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/overview_about_pe.html